# "Leiden können"/"nicht leiden können" ist ein Problem für mich. Do I get the meaning of the sentence right?

Tags: meaning

Ich lese jetzt "Casanovas Heimfahrt" von Arthur Schnitzler. Hier ist der Satz:

> Wir wohnen ja längst nicht mehr in der Stadt, die ich übrigens niemals habe leiden können, so wenig wie Amalia sie leiden mag.

Ich verstehe den Satz auf diese Weise: Olivo konnte es nie genießen, dass er und Amalia von der Stadt zum Lande umgezogen sind, ebenso wie Amalia auch kein Spaß davon hatte.

Es gibt aber so viele Negationen und Vergleiche hier, dass ich gar nicht sicher bin, ob ich es richtig oder nicht richtig verstanden habe.

Comment: Lies auch diese Frage: [Why does “Leidenschaft” mean “passion” while “leiden” means “to suffer”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32111/why-does-leidenschaft-mean-passion-while-leiden-means-to-suffer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nein, du hast es falsch verstanden. Die beiden mögen laut der Aussage die Stadt nicht leiden.

> Wir wohnen ja längst nicht mehr in der Stadt, …

Dieser Teil dürfte klar sein.

> … , die ich übrigens niemals habe leiden können, …

Olivo konnte die Stadt niemals leiden.

> …, so wenig wie Amalia sie leiden mag.

Für Amalia gilt zumindest momentan genau dasselbe.

---

Die Floskel *etwas leiden können* bedeutet *etwas mögen*.

> Ich kann dich gut leiden. == Ich mag dich sehr.
>
> Ich kann ihn nicht leiden. == Ich hasse ihn.

Die Floskel *etwas leiden mögen* bedeutet genau das gleiche.

Comment: Nur weil ich jemanden nicht leiden kann, hasse ich ihn nicht gleich. Hassen ist deutlich stärker.

Comment: "Ich kann ihn nicht leiden" is better translated as "I can't stand him"

Comment: "Ich kann ihn nicht leiden. == Ich hasse ihn" Das stimmt so nicht!

Comment: Jemanden nicht leiden können bedeutet nur, ihn nicht zu mögen! Jemanden nicht zu mögen ist aber was ganz anderes, als ihn zu hassen!

Comment: Es ist nicht etwas ganz anderes. Es gibt Überschneidungen und Unterschiede in den Bedeutungen, je nach Kontext. *nicht leiden könne* lässt durchaus offen, ob damit Hass gemeint ist. *hassen* bedeutet in jedem Fall *nicht Leiden können (wollen)*.

Answer (score 2):

Versuchen wir es mit *mögen* und *ausstehen können*, vielleicht hilft dir das.

> Wir wohnen ja längst nicht mehr in der Stadt, die ich übrigens niemals
>   habe leiden können, so wenig wie Amalia sie leiden mag.
>
> Wir wohnen ja längst nicht mehr in der Stadt, die ich übrigens niemals
>   gemocht habe, so wenig wie Amalia sie mag.
>
> Wir wohnen ja längst nicht mehr in der Stadt, die ich übrigens niemals
>   ausstehen konnte, so wenig wie Amalia sie ausstehen kann.

Answer (score 2):

*Leiden* ist verwandt mit *loath*. Komischer weise ist die Bedeutung aber fast entgegen gesetzt, aber nicht gleich stark:

> *I loathe this city* (Ich kann die Stadt nicht leiden).

Das erklärt sich sicher analog zu *ertragen*, *ausstehen*:

*Ich kann diese Stadt nicht ertragen* (this city is insufferable).

*loath, Leid* weisen starke ähnlichkeit auf mit *oath, Eid*. In diesem Sinne erinnert die Phrase an *abschwören* (renounce, leave for good, swear off), sowie *Ausstand* "Abschied, Abschiedsfeier" (vgl. *ausstehen können*).

Comment: "Ich kann X nicht leiden" --> "I can't stand X". "Ich kann X gut leiden" --> "I like X much"